# Wanting to make existing 2-wire 220V outlet a 4-wire one

Tags: wiring, receptacle, grounding, 240v

(Located in the USA)
I've inherited a 220V (or 240V?) circuit which is just capped off inside a junction box.  It's hooked up to a 30A breaker, and seems fine, except that it's only a 3-wire run--no ground.  I'd like to make it usable for running some 220V computer equipment, but I need a ground to do so.

I'm about 10' from the breaker box, inside a washer/dryer closet, but the wire was pulled through the walls.  Should I run conduit with a ground wire in it from the nearby breaker box and pull it into the junction box with the other three wires?  Suggestions?

I just want to do this correctly, and safely the first time!

---

Well, now it appears I remembered incorrectly...there are only TWO wires!  What were they thinking when they did this?  More importantly, what should I do to safely fix this for me and anyone who might later open this up to work on it?

[image: insane 2-wire 220v thing]

Comment: These may answer your question about a "retrofit ground" (https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/99429/house-wiring-and-grounding-how-do-you-retrofit-an-old-house-and-ground-it) and (https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36350/how-do-i-add-grounding-to-my-old-electrical-wiring)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add grounding to my old electrical wiring?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36350/how-do-i-add-grounding-to-my-old-electrical-wiring)

Comment: **beware old answers**. The rules were greatly liberalized in 2016 (NEC 2014) .

Comment: What wiring method was used for the homerun of this circuit?  Are you OK with having *only* 240V at this location?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, yes, I've got lots of open breaker slots, so I'm fine with only having 220V here.

Comment: Can you tell us what wiring method was used here? Was the existing circuit wired using a plastic-sheathed cable, some sort of metal-armored cable, or wires in some sort of conduit?

Comment: Well, this may be more complicated than I thought...I guess I remembered the number of wires incorrectly...there are only TWO!  What did this person do??  (Adding photo to initial post if possible)

Comment: How much power does said 220V computer equipment pull?

Comment: Maximum I'd ever plan to pull here would be somewhere between 6 to 8 amps.

Comment: Can you make this computer equipment run on 120V instead?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, yes, I could run it on 120V (the power supply says both 100-140VAC input and 200-240VAC input).  Since I had the unused '220V', and since I think I read that the power usage is more efficient on 220V, I just thought I could utilize this as a 220V circuit.

Comment: FWIW, I was going to use a NEMA 6-30R here, which only specifies black, white, and ground...is that still safe here without a neutral?

Comment: Can you figure out what wiring method is running to that box? It *looks* like armored cable, but I can't tell for sure

Comment: Well, nevermind...I just uncapped the wires to verify which breaker they went with and they are totally dead.  :/  Thanks for helping me troubleshoot this, but it looks like if I want a 240V receptacle here I'm going to be doing a homerun anyway.